# Using an editor to stage files in git

Tags: git

When I do an interactive rebase, git opens up an editor in which I can specify the changes I want to make (pick a commit, reword a commit message, etc.):

```
p 99ba2e6 commit message ...
r 65b35d4 commit message ...
p f793a28 commit message ...
p d122650 commit message ...
```

Can I somehow use an editor to stage files in a similar way? For example, lets assume I have the following three modified files (`git status -s`):

```
M ../path/to/file1
M ../other/path/to/file2
M ../yet/other/path/to/file3
```

I would like git to open an editor so I can stage the first two of them like this:

```
A ../path/to/file1
A ../other/path/to/file2
M ../yet/other/path/to/file3
```

I know about `git add -i` and `git gui`, but I really would like to use an editor to do this, just like I do when I am doing interactive rebases.

Comment: There isn’t such a thing, but you could write a script that does it.

Comment: I suspect you need to specify an editor to get a useful answer.  For example, I'd be amazed if emacs didn't have at least 3 ways to do this, but in that case you may be better asking on the emacs stackexchange.  For other editors you could specify one in your question.

Comment: @CroadLangshan: I want the solution to be editor-agnostic, just like interactive rebasing (when you run `git rebase -i`, git opens up an editor based on the value of `core.editor` or the `EDITOR` environment variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a script [git-edit-index](https://github.com/s3rvac/git-edit-index) that does exactly this. It is editor-agnostic, i.e. it respects the git's `core.editor` setting or the `EDITOR` environment variable.